# Where is the LocalResources saved when running in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm creating some custom application logs in my web application with log4net for my Azure WebRole.

These are moved to blob storage every hour by the DiagnosticManager. My setup is the same as the [code sample on windowesazure.com](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/#custom).

When running the Azure Emulator i can open the directory of the local storage at any time to read the logs before they're moved to blob storage.

How can I browse the local storage when deployed in the real cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalStorage is a VHD that is mounted within an Azure role instance when that instance is started up. The only external visiblity to that VHD is to remote desktop into the machine and browse it there. The VHD is not accessible outside of the instance to which it is attached.

Comment: Ok. I've been using remote desktop but I just can't find it. Shouldn't it be visible as a drive?

Comment: Yes, you should have 3 drives mounted on the VM. The OS, your app, and the localstorage area.

Answer (score 3):

Look in `C:\resources\directories`, IIRC.

Comment: `C:\Resources\Directory`, to be more precise